# Will ROS2 support PyPy?

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will ROS2 ([`rclpy`](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy), etc.) support [PyPy](https://pypy.org/) which would enable better performance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291981/will-ros2-support-pypy?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no plan to do so, no. But anyone from the community could try to get it working. We do, however, make heavy use of C extensions, so I don't know well those integrate into PyPy. Last time I looked at it, PyPy only supported FFI-like bindings. Our current implementation uses CPython directly from C code to create PyObjects and stuff like that.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-23**:
What's your estimated effort for rclpy only? :)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-05-23**:
I have no idea. Assuming you go with the CFFI route (reusing our C API), you'll still have to write a lot of conversion code in Python and deal with generate messages (not sure if the generated Python messages will work as-is). It might be a considerable effort, but I don't know for sure.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-24**:
W.r.t. parallel thread execution: [PyPy suffers from GIL](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-pypy-have-a-gil-why) (like e.g. CPython does) and the GIL-free [pypy-stm](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/stm.html#caveats) is highly experimental.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-05-26**:
Just for completion: Multiprocessing allows parallel execution until the number of processors is reached. Has in comparison to multithreading some advantages/disadvantages.